# Slack app: Sending messages to this app has been turned off

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I created a slack app and add the following scopes to it:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But it still shows "Sending messages to this app has been turned off." in the chat window.
[image]
The app configuration page has been updated recently, so I can't try the method such as "go to App Home and set the checkbox for 'Allow users to send Slash commands and messages from the messages tab'".

Actually the settings I made for this app is the same with another app which I created previously and runs normally.

Does anybody have suggestions for this problem? It confuses me a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, the only way to do this is : 1. Go to App Home 2. Enable Messages tab 3. Check 'Allow users to send Slash commands and messages...'

Comment: @SuyashGaur Thank you for your reply. But I have no idea how to set this in the new configuration page, there is no APP HOME anymore...

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
features:
    app_home:
      home_tab_enabled: false
      messages_tab_enabled: true
      messages_tab_read_only_enabled: false
```

to the app Manifest.